# Should be returning true but returns false instead?

Tags: java, bukkit

Code:

```
Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("Check " + ChatColor.stripColor(i));
Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("That it starts with " + ChatColor.stripColor(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&',      GUIShop.instance.getConfig().getString("Messages." + type + "Label"))));
Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.stripColor(i).startsWith(ChatColor.stripColor(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', GUIShop.instance.getConfig().getString("Messages." + type + "Label")))) + "");
```

And image of it returning false instead of true:
[image]

Could me being stupid.. Not sure

EDIT1: Ok so thanks to eckes he pointed out that I was being stupid.. How would I check if "Buy: 50.0" started with "Buy: Price". Like if up to %price%

Comment: 223 columns is extremely long for a single line, you should consider splitting it up into several lines.

Comment: `stripColor` really does sound like a mutable operation.  Not knowing anything of Bukkit's API, are you sure that call doesn't mutate state?

Comment: https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/ChatColor.java#L187 in reply to @Makoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False is correct, "`Buy: 50.0`" does not start with "`Buy: %price%`". And you should really not mix color logic with translation logic with business logic.

Make your code readable, it often helps to find the problem yourself.

If you want to remove %price% you could use:

```
String check = ChatColor.stripColor(i);
String pattern = ChatColor.stripColor(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&',   
                   GUIShop.instance.getConfig().getString("Messages." + type + "Label")));
pattern = pattern.replace(" %price%", "");
boolean isBuy = check.startsWith(pattern);
```

I cant make it much more readable without more background details.

Comment: I ended up using the split method, not sure which is best but thanks for your help!

Comment: In this case i remove a fixed string, you might want to parse at blank or % or similiar.